# How to pass dynamic value in swift enum

Tags: ios, swift

I am using Enum in swift I am looking to pass dynamic value, but not sure how to achieve it ?

I want to pass dynamic value in `.revisit` case

Here is my code example: -

```
enum MyEnum: String, CaseIterable {
    case revision
    case revisit
  
    var getDescription: String {
        switch self {
        case .revision:
            return "Do revision"
        case .revisit:
            return "You answered 3 Out Of 3 Questions re-start ?" // How to pass dynamic value instead of 3 & 3
        }
    }
}
```

By using `CaseIterable` I am using it on `UITableViewCell` & want to change data of revisit dynamically

Comment: Turn it into a function and pass the value as an argument

Comment: Have you checked enum associated value?

Comment: Kindly add as an answer ? @PratikPrajapati

Answer (score 1):

Better way make pass dynamic value in enum

```
  enum MyEnum: String, CaseIterable {
    case revision
    case revisit

    private var dynamicValues: (Int, Int)? {
        switch self {
        case .revision:
            return nil
        case .revisit:
            return (3, 3) // Default values
        }
    }

    var getDescription: String {
        switch self {
        case .revision:
            return "Do revision"
        case .revisit:
            if let (value1, value2) = dynamicValues {
                return "You answered \(value1) Out Of \(value2) Questions re-start ?"
            } else {
                return "You answered some questions. Re-start?"
            }
        }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since enums in Swift do not support stored values, it's often a better option to use a struct to wrap this enum. This approach allows you to associate additional data with each enum case, providing greater flexibility and versatility.

but you can use some hacks like global variables, [objc_getAssociatedObject](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/1418865-objc_getassociatedobject), and [objc_setAssociatedObject](https://objc_setassociatedobject), or leverage static variables to achieve similar functionality.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```swift
var i:Int = 2;

enum MyEnum: String, CaseIterable {
    case revision
    case revisit
  
    var getDescription: String {
        switch self {
        case .revision:
            return "Do revision"
        case .revisit:
            return "You answered \(i) Out Of 3 Questions re-start ?" // How to pass dynamic value instead of 3 & 3
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**